# transform template v-for into computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I'm looping over an array, check the index of my array (`indexArray`) with the index of my component (`indexChild`) and then it should write the value which is in my indexArray in my `b-form-input` `v-model`.

How can I transform this code into a computed function? I know that I have to filter it but I don't know how to solve that .

```
<div v-for="(ID, indexChild) in 3" :key="indexChild">
  <div v-for="(item, indexArray) in Array" :key="indexArray">
    <div v-if="indexArray == indexChild">
      <b-form-input type="number" :v-model="item"></b-form-input> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my Array `console.log`:

```
(3) ['1234', '4321', '1379']
 ▼
  0: "1234"
  1: "4321"
  2: "1379"
```

Comment: What is the content of `Array`? Why should you iterate over a number? `:v-model` is incorrect syntax! `:key="index"` index doesn't exist here. Sorry! but I can't figure it out

Comment: Array = ```['1234', '4321', '1379']```. I need to check if my ```indexArray``` = ```indexChild``` to get the correct input in my b-form. If ```indexChild = 0```, I check my ```indexArray``` which value is in ```indexArray[0]```and want to input ```1234``` in my ```b-form```

Answer (score 0):

Just return an item in your array by index that you already know, no need to iterate:

```js
computed: {
  itemOfInterest(){
    return this.yourArray[this.indexChild]
  }
}
```

To address the update in the original post. You can still do this in your template

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(ID, indexChild) in 3" :key="indexChild">
    <b-form-input type="number" :v-model="Array[indexChild]"></b-form-input>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: but I don't need only one item.. I need the matching item based on my indexes..

Comment: From what I see in your template you're using only one item

Comment: you still do not need to iterate over the array in your updated example. just access the item in your array by index